# How to Reset the Configuration of a Netapp Disk Array?

Tags: configuration

I've acquired several Netapp disk arrays that have a prior configuration which needs to be reset, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this as it seems to require a connector that I've never seen before.

What type of connector is this for the serial port?

It's very similar to: [NetApp Drive Module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265030049018?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=265030049018&targetid=1263433205934&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9004572&poi=&campaignid=10459842381&mkgroupid=122657840056&rlsatarget=aud-622027676548:pla-1263433205934&abcId=2146002&merchantid=101988578)
, and looks like:

[image: Drive Module]

What I presume the serial port is:

[image]

What connector can I use to connect to this so I can reset the configuration, and is there a terminal guide for such an action?

**EDIT 0:**

The cable appears to be a PS/2 data port:

[image]

although as to how I can reset over the serial port... I'm not entirely certain.

Should I try this port to VGA, or ethernet, or USB? I have no idea how to handle this? Does a PS/2 keyboard connect to it? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried looking for documentation? That's your best bet to find out how to reset them.

Comment: I think that's easier said than done. It's not labeled very well, and I couldn't find any documentation on it.